# How to convert CComBSTR to LPCSTR

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have CComBSTR in my code and have to pass it to function with argument type LPCSTR.
How to convert **CComBSTR to LPCSTR**?

Comment: See some info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=msvc-170.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the ATL way would be using [Using MFC MBCS/Unicode Conversion Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn059-using-mfc-mbcs-unicode-conversion-macros):

```
void SomeCode()
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    CComBSTR bstr(L"hello world");
    LPCSTR lp = W2CA(bstr); // bstr is a LPWSTR
}
```